# `web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters()` not returning correct values

Tags: web3js, abi, eth-call

I call to a method that returns two contract addresses, like this, where `method` is the method object taken from the ABI (triple-checked that already):

```js
web3.eth.call(
    {
        from: account,
        to: contract,
        data: web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(method, [])
    },
    "latest",
    callback
)
```

For all the methods I call that return a single value, everything works fine. But with this one, which returns two values, it seems to be something wrong.
I receive the following result: `0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019434f4e545241545f494e41435449462f5452414e534645524500000000000000`

And, when trying to decode it :

```js
web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters([{"internalType": "contract MyData","name": "dat","type": "address"},{"internalType": "contract Data","name": "_dat","type": "address"}],"0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019434f4e545241545f494e41435449462f5452414e534645524500000000000000")
```

The result is:

```js
{
  '0': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '1': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  __length__: 2,
  dat: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  _dat: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
}
```

I also tried with

```js
web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(["address","address"],"0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019434f4e545241545f494e41435449462f5452414e534645524500000000000000")
```

which gives me

```js
{
  '0': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '1': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  __length__: 2
}
```

> The expect result should be :
>
> ```js
> {
>   '0': '0xEed7569548df9BAD3D770D1B7767B752698449ee',
>   '1': '0xC7D9037067E161E9E9d20Cdab3BCA0ba0c9a97ea
> ',
>   __length__: 2,
>   dat: '0xEed7569548df9BAD3D770D1B7767B752698449ee',
>   _dat: '0xC7D9037067E161E9E9d20Cdab3BCA0ba0c9a97ea
> '
> }
> ```

Can someone point me if there is something wrong in the decode function, or in the call itself ?
Should I maybe convert the returned string in some way before calling `abi.decodeParameters()` ?

### Edit:

I was using `web3js` `v1.2.7`.
I upgraded to `v1.2.9`, and now, there is an error thrown apparently from the `decodeParameters` method:

```
dat: value out of range (argument="value", value=20, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.2)
```

Comment: The first 4 bytes from the output look like method's signature [Error(string)](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x08c379a0). Are you testing against geth? There is/was an issue between geth/web3 in the case a call to a view function reverts with a message (https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/pull/3571). It seems to be fixed in github but it hasn't been released yet.

Comment: I'm testing this on ganache-cli for now.
Thanks for the clues. I'll investigate further.